# why my new route Map for MVC does not work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

this app is out of the box mvc4 internet app from vs2012 templates. i have added a *new route pat*h for the **url** pattern `sports/{name}`

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Sports",
                "sports/{name}",
                new { controller="sports", action="Find",name=UrlParameter.Optional }
                );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

the controller the home page is

```
public class sportsController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /sports/

    public ActionResult Find(string strName)
    {
        return Content("Sport looking for is: "+ strName);
    }

}
```

the page works and displays the text *"Sport looking for is"* if i request the default home page **http:/localhost/sports**.  But if pass a parameter to the **url** such as `"tennis"` that parameter wont get passed to the action method `Find()`.

[here is the video of what happening](https://youtu.be/iIxFLCczfM0), i want to know why this does not pass the parameter and how to fix this?

thanks

Comment: Stephen's answer is technically correct, but are you sure you want to restrict your controller to just one action? The route you define assumes the Sports controller will always invoke the Find action. In fact, you cannot invoke any other action even if you wanted to. For example, if your expecting the find to return a list of sports that might then click through to a detail about each sport in the list, you would need to create another controller for that detail action.

Comment: @S.Brentson you are correct! : ) this app is for a demo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You route defines a parameter `name = UrlParameter.Optional` but the method your calling has a parameter `string strName` (they do not match). Change the method signature to

```
public ActionResult Find(string name)
```